# MongoDB Replica Set, initiate() need to login error

Tags: replication, mongodb, replica-set

I am trying to setup a replica set, but when I issue:

```
rs.initiate()
```

On the first server, I get the following error:

```
{ "errmsg" : "need to login", "ok" : 0 }
```

That is strange though, because in my configuration `auth: true` is commented out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have `auth: true` commented out, but did you start with `--auth` or `--keyFile` or specify `keyFile` in the config file?  Setting the [`keyFile`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/replica-sets/#security-considerations-for-replica-sets) enables authentication implicitly, so that could be your issue here.

If you want to be completely sure, temporarily shut down the `mongod` instance and start it manually, specifying only the basics (port, replica set name etc.) explicitly.  At least then you can be sure of what is and is not enabled.

For a running instance you can get the current options parsed from the top of the log file for the instance - they are printed out as part of the startup messaging.  You can also get them by running: [`getCmdLineOpts`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/) (note though that this requires admin rights, so you may see issues if you are running with auth on and don't have an admin user defined).

Comment: That was the problem, had `keyFile` on.